# Property 'attr' does not exist on type 'void' in vs code

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

```
public update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {
    // Add your Power BI visual update code here
    // ...
    // Call the ChatGPT API with a sample prompt and your API key
    callChatGPTAPI("Integrate Power BI with ChatGPT", "<your_openai_api_key>")
        .then(response => {
            // Display the response in a text element
            const textElement = this.target.append("text")
                .attr("x", 10)
                .attr("y", 50)
                .text(response);
            // Update the text element with the response from ChatGPT
            textElement.text(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error calling ChatGPT API:", error);
        });
}
```

When i run this code i'm getting error like **Property 'attr' does not exist on type 'void' in vs code**
I have added my api key.

How do i fix this?

Comment: `java` != `javascript`

Comment: Print `this.target` to the console before calling `this.target.append("text")`. What do you see?